# Reverse image search (of the type Google's "Search by image" can *not* do)

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition

I would have thought Google Images' algorithms are by now sophisticated enough that their "Search by image" feature does a pretty good job idenityfing web pages where the same or a similar image can be found.

[image]

To my surprise, this seems to not be the case. I wanted to identify where a certain location was (image below is cropped from an unknown tourism recommendations website), but "Search by image" was not able to locate the exact website that hosts that (or a similar) image.

[image]

Using the "visually similar" option in Google Images doesn't help, as images are suggested which are only roughly similar (mountain landscapes, in this case), but clearly represent different locations.

To clarify, I am not expecting this kind of search to produce amazing results, such as invariance to lighting conditions, camera angle etc; but simply invariance to trivial image parameters such as cropping, panning, global brightness adjustments etc

Since Google Images is clearly not (yet) the flagship reverse image search, can anyone recommend another search engine of this sort that can do the job?

Comment: This image is on the web, and Google Images can not find it, that's the problem if I understand correctly?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The image has likely been cropped from some recommendations website (which I do not know), so may not appear identically on there. I'd have liked to find that (or some other) website where the image appears (in a recognisable form), so as to infer from the text where the location is.

Comment: Please replace ` did a rubbish job at it` with an exact description of what displeased you. Thanks!

Comment: Good point - will do